# Excel 2013 formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to come up with formula in excel for the following:

I have several columns that have the following criteria Civil Est 1 through to Civils Est 5 also Status Est 1 through to Status Est 5

In each of the Civils Est there is Completed or Not Completed or the cell is blank.  In the Status Est there are a series of numbers.

What I want is if one of the Civils Est column has the statement not complete I want it to return the value from the relevant Status Est column.

[image]

Comment: What would help is some test data and expected output in tabular form so we can copy and paste it into excel and test formulas.  Please [Edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1123586/edit) your original post and include the data and expected outcome.

Comment: So, **if** something matches something, **then** do something?

Comment: Scott will send over shortly

Comment: You just want the first "not completed"?

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:J2,MATCH("Not Completed",A2:J2,0)-1)
```

This will find the first `Not Completed` and return the value directly to the Left of it.

[image]